# MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not working on Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv

I am developing app that accesses text files created by users on Android TV (I want to support Android 5 to 12). Since Android 11, [requestLegacyExternalStorage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage) is ignored, so I want to use [MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) to access files.

This is my sample code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Application works fine when I test on my phone, but it crashes on Android TV with this error:

```
AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION dat=package:io.github.anenasa.news.debug }
```

I also try `ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` but I get a similar error. Is `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` not supported on Android TV or I make a mistake somewhere?

Note: I also tried some alternatives:

1. Storage Access Framework: This is the first method I come up with, but [SAF is not supported on Android TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679867/storage-access-framework-not-working-on-android-tv).
2. [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media): Partially working, but I have to rename the extension from .txt to media types like .mp4, because this is for accessing media files but not text files.
3. [Opt out of scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage): Change targetSdkVersion to 29 and set requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". The only working method I found so far.
4. [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific): File I want to read is created by user, and they are unable to put the file in app-specific external storage since Android 11.

Comment: "I want to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to access files" -- that may preclude you from distributing the app on the Play Store and elsewhere. "Is MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not supported on Android TV" -- that is probably a true statement. Many Android TV devices have limited storage; Google is not encouraging developers to deal with much in the way of local files. "I also tried some alternatives" -- use `getExternalFilesDir()` (method on `Context`).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your reply. "that may preclude you from distributing the app on the Play Store and elsewhere" -- I only distribute on github, so that doesn't matter. "use getExternalFilesDir()" -- I forget to mention that file I want to read is created by user, and they are unable to put the file in app-specific external storage since Android 11. (I suggested my users to use `adb push` to copy file from computer to TV, but one said that he didn't have a computer.) I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no answer for a month, I will answer my question.

After testing on multiple versions of Android TV in emulator, I found that MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is only available in Android TV 13, not in Android TV 11 and 12.